# Angular ngFor on method issue adding variable on second parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have a method that does a replace:

```
replace('{findThis}', 'Replace with value');
```

So below I have:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of data">
    <li (click)="replace('{current}', {{item}})">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

But `{{item}}` in the second parameter is returning:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of data">
    <li (click)="replace('{current}', item)">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```